# check if multiple records exist in table ORACLE PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, exists, records

Here I want to check if record exists and based on that I want perform actions.
My code is as below

```
     FOR cell_configs IN (SELECT cc.cell_configuration_name,
                                 cc.cell_configuration_value
                            from cell_configurations cc
                            where (cc.cell_configuration_name like height_cc or 
                                    cc.cell_configuration_name like width_cc) and
                                  cc.cell_id=c_id)        
    LOOP
      if cc.cell_configuration_name OR
         cc.cell_configuration_value EXISTS
      then
        -- i want to update the table  dbms_output.put_line(temp || ' does exist');
      else
        -- i want to insert records into the table dbms_output.put_line(temp || ' does not exist');
      end if;

      dbms_output.put_line(c_id || ' ' || 
                           cell_configs.cell_configuration_name || ' ' ||  
                           cell_configs.cell_configuration_value );
    END LOOP;
```

If there are no records found I can see that I will get empty string i.e ''. I cannot check if it is null or not.

Can anybody help me on this please?.

### EDIT (info copied from comments):

I am looking for these 2 rows(height,width) cell_configuration_name like 'container.dealer-content.configs[1].width' or cell_configuration_name like 'container.dealer-content.configs[1].height' cell_configuration_value=flex-width-8 cell_configuration_value=flex-width-250

CELL_CONFIGURATIONS table below

```
CELL_CONFIGURATION_ID     NUMBER(38,0) PK
CELL_ID                   NUMBER(38,0) FK
CELL_CONFIGURATION_NAME   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
CELL_CONFIGURATION_VALUE  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
IS_LOCKED                 CHAR(1 BYTE)
MODIFIED_BY               VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
MODIFIED_DATE             DATE
CREATED_BY                VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
CREATED_DATE
```

Sample Data as Below

```
CELL_ID     CELL_CONFIGURATION_NAME         CELL_CONFIGURATION_VALUE
37771286880 container.dealer-content.configs[1].height  flex-height-2
37771286880 container.dealer-content.configs[1].width   flex-width-8
```

Comment: Your query already lists only the records that exists on your table, so unless there are other table involved, your logic does not make sense. Please change your question to be more specific. If you have another table to check, then the best approach would query this other table, with the key needed, using a count(*) for example. If return <> 0, the record exists, 0 othwerwise.

Comment: Sounds like you need to investigate the MERGE statement.

Comment: The statement inside the for loop will not execute if there are no records. So  what you are trying to do will not work.

Comment: Actually i am filtering based on 2 values i.e. width_cc or height_cc so if there is only width found then i want to insert height or vice-versa. How can i do that?

Comment: @cableload Yes. you are right. If there are no records found, my query will not execute. but if any one of the 2 records found then my query will get execute and i need to insert the other one. Any idea how can i check that which record is found and which record do i need to insert? thanks

Comment: Can you please put the structure of your table, with PK, etc...? Please list some sample data and the expected result. I think your case can be solved in a single query.

Comment: Additional information should not be put into comments - instead, the question should be edited and the new information added to the question itself. I've done it for you this time. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much @BobJarvis.

Comment: Thanks for the table structure. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel  i have updated the question with sample date. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, in this case, what should happen with this data, when pass through your procedure? And if the cell_id is different for each row?

Comment: Usually every cell_id has 2 rows i.e  height and width if not i want to insert these 2 rows, when this passes through my procedure every cell_id should have both height and width(configuration_name and configuration_value). Thanks you @Walter_Ritzel

Answer (score 0):

Here is the beggining of a solution...

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec IN
  (SELECT cell_id  -- assuming that cell_id will repeat for lines with width and height
  FROM CELL_CONFIGURATIONS
  WHERE CELL_CONFIGURATION_NAME LIKE height_cc
  MINUS
  SELECT cell_id
  FROM CELL_CONFIGURATIONS
  WHERE CELL_CONFIGURATION_NAME LIKE width_cc
  )
  LOOP
     -- INSERT STATEMENT
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Here we will end up inserting irrespective of existence of the records. Because if both height_cc and width_cc are available then also we will insert.